# Prove that series with $(-1)^k\cos^3(k)$ has sequence of partial sums bounded.

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

I found that $(-1)^k\cos^3(k)$ equals $$(1-sin^2(k))cos((\pi+1)k)$$ or $$cos((\pi+3)k) + sin(k)sin((\pi+2)k) + sin(k)cos(k)sin((\pi+1)k)$$.

I wanted to flatten it into such a sum of terms that each has bounded partial sums, so the final sequence of partial sums is bounded too.

But I got the $sin(k)$ and $sin(k)cos(k)$.

I should use that $(-1)^k$ equals $cos(\pi k)$ and the trigonometric identities.

Comment: Stick with sines and cosines.

Comment: The simplest way is to use $\cos(x)=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}2$ and then use [the formula for the partial sum of a geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
&\left|\,\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k\cos^3(k)\,\right|\\
&=\left|\,\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^k}8\left(e^{ik}+e^{-ik}\right)^3\,\right|\\
&=\left|\,\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^k}8\left(e^{3ik}+3e^{ik}+3e^{-ik}+e^{-3ik}\right)\,\right|\\
&\le\frac18\left|\,\frac{1-\left(-e^{3i}\right)^n}{1+e^{3i}}\,\right|+\frac38\left|\,\frac{1-\left(-e^{i}\right)^n}{1+e^{i}}\,\right|+\frac38\left|\,\frac{1-\left(-e^{-i}\right)^n}{1+e^{-i}}\,\right|+\frac18\left|\,\frac{1-\left(-e^{-3i}\right)^n}{1+e^{-3i}}\,\right|\\
&\le\frac1{4\cos\left(\frac32\right)}+\frac3{4\cos\left(\frac12\right)}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thanks, I don’t see the last inequality though. But as $e^{bi}$ is for b periodic and bounded (?) the cosines should be bounded too

Comment: @Adam: $\left|\,1+e^{3i}\,\right|=\left|\,1+e^{-3i}\,\right|=\left|\,e^{-3i/2}+e^{3i/2}\,\right|=2\cos\left(\frac32\right)$ and $\left|\,1+e^{i}\,\right|=\left|\,1+e^{-i}\,\right|=\left|\,e^{-i/2}+e^{i/2}\,\right|=2\cos\left(\frac12\right)$. Furthermore, $\left|\,1-\left(-e^{ix}\right)^n\,\right|\le2$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** By the triple angle formula, $(\cos \theta)^3$ is a linear combination of $\cos (3\theta)$ and $\cos \theta$.

---

> For each $\alpha,\beta$ the partial sums of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \cos(k\alpha+\beta)$ are bounded. (It is the difference of geometric series $\sum \exp(i(k\alpha+\beta)) - \sum \exp(-i(k\alpha+\beta))$.)
>
>  Apply this to $\sum \cos(2k)$, $\sum \cos(2k+1)$ for the series $\sum (-1)^k \cos k$ and to $\sum \cos(6k)$, $\sum \cos(6k+3)$ for the series $\sum (-1)^k \cos (3k)$

Answer (score -1):

The partial sum sequence will look like
$a_n= \sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^kcos^3(k)$ Now write, $4cos^3(k)=cos(3k)+3cos(k)$. Then try to use the triangle inequality.